# Google Analytics: Use multiple unknown trackers

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm using Google analytics on a website which is being tracked by multiple accounts. Since some of the trackers are added dynamically as part of the response from the web server, there is no easy way for me to know which page is tracked by which accounts. I.e. I don't have the names of the trackers.

I want to find an easy way to send events to all trackers, without knowing which trackers are currently active for a specific page.

I found that all trackers can be listen with the var `ga.getAll()` method, as found in an example on https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/method-reference#blownaway

```
ga(function() {
  var trackers = ga.getAll();
  for (var i=0; i<trackers.length; ++i) {
    var tracker = trackers[i];
    tracker.send('pageview');
  }
});
```

Instead of doing `ga('myTracker.send', 'pageview')` I could use the code above to send to all trackers. But I want to be able to do something in the terms of `ga('allTrackers.send', 'pageview')` to not have to duplicate the code above everywhere I want to send commands. Another option being to create custom methods for each type of call, but I do many different calls with different parameters, so that doesn't seem like a good way either. I'm sure that there must be some way to do it which is more scalable and less repetitive than the ones above.

I want to add this behaviour for `allTrackers.send`, `allTrackers.ecommerce:addTransaction`, `allTrackers.ecommerce:addItem` and `allTrackers.ecommerce:send`. (Ecommerce refers to https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingEcommerce)

Cheers!

EDIT:

I just noticed that the ecommerce part doesn't work with MisterPhilip's solution below, the code is returning "require does not exist on the ga tracker #0", "ecommerce:addTransaction does not exist on the ga tracker #0", "ecommerce:addItem does not exist on the ga tracker", "ecommerce:send does not exist on the ga tracker #0".

These methods are a bit different than the others, since they used to be called by myTracker.ecommerce:send, instead of just myTracker.send 
I guess the method needs to be updated to handle the "ecommerce:" but I don't know how.

Here's the code I'm trying to call which returns the errors:

```
allGa('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');

allGa('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    'id': '1234',
    'affiliation': 'myCompany',
    'revenue': '27.55',
    'shipping': '0',
    'tax': '0',
    'currency': 'USD'
});

allGa('ecommerce:addItem', {
    'id': '1234',
    'name': 'MyProduct (Blue - XL)',
    'sku': '',
    'category': 'myCompany',
    'price': '25.99',
    'quantity': '1',
    'currency': 'USD'
});

allGa('ecommerce:send');

allGa('send', {
    'hitType': 'event',        
    'eventCategory': 'checkout', 
    'eventAction': 'view',    
    'eventLabel': 'completed'
});

allGa('send', 'pageview', '/checkout/complete');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you provided is along the right track. I've made a basic function that can simply replace `ga( ... )` with `allGa( ... )`. This allows you to have a drop-in replacement, thanks to using `.apply()`

```
function allGa()
{
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments),
      method = args[0];
      ga = window.ga;

  if(method.indexOf('.') > 0)
  {
    // We only want to pass to 1 tracker
    ga.apply(ga, arguments);
  }
  else
  {
    // Grab all of the trackers
    ga(function()
    {
      var trackers = ga.getAll();      
      for (var i=0; i<trackers.length; ++i)
      {
        try {
          var name = trackers[i].get('name'),
              argsLocal = args.slice();

          // Change the tracker name to the prefixed version
          argsLocal[0] = name + '.' + argsLocal[0];

          // Call the tracking call for this tracker
          ga.apply(ga, argsLocal);
        }
        catch(e)
        {
          console.error(e.msg);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Sending a pageview to all trackers:

```
allGa('send', 'pageview');
```

Sending an event to all trackers:

```
allGa('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'label');
```

Setting a dimension:

```
allGa('set', 'dimension1', 'testing');
```

Sending a pageview to a single tracker

```
allGa('foobar.send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MisterPhilip. Unfortunately, `allGa('myTracker.send', 'pageview');` returns an error, "myTracker.send does not exist on the ga tracker" but the regular method `ga('myTracker.send', 'pageview');` still works.

Comment: That's because you were calling a single tracker (`myTracker`). I've updated the code so it checks for this.

Comment: I just noticed that the ecommerce part doesn't work with this solution, the code is returning "require does not exist on the ga tracker #0", "ecommerce:addTransaction does not exist on the ga tracker #0", "ecommerce:addItem does not exist on the ga tracker", "ecommerce:send does not exist on the ga tracker #0". See EDIT above.

Comment: MisterPhilip do you know how to add support for the "ecommerce:methodNameHere" methods?